# How do I use Fandango with Passbook?

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

I just purchased a ticket for a movie tonight using the Fandango app on my iPhone 4S running iOS 6. I know that [Fandango is one of the current few Passbook supported apps](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/09/19/list_of_passbook_supported_apps_appears_in_ios_6_app_store). What I don't know is how to ensure that my tickets will show up in Passbook. Is there anything special I have to do? The Walgreens app prompted me to put my card in Passbook so I was expecting similar behavior from Fandango. Will the tickets just show up in Passbook closer to showtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain theaters are capable of mobile ticketing. In the Fandango app when viewing theaters which can accept mobile tickets you will see a notification which says "Mobile ticket available." If you do not see this indicator a mobile device cannot be used as a ticket at this theater and therefore tickets will not show up in Passbook. That said, you can still purchase tickets for the theater and use a confirmation code at the box office.

Comment: This is a nice example of how apps can initially "support" passbook but it takes time (weeks to months) and updates to the app on the store to really integrate at a deeper level with passbook.